# Greater Than Time Fields RXWeb Reactive Form Validators

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I need to validate if the end time field is greater than the start time field.
I defined the following rx model:

```
@required()
@time() 
start: Time;

@time() 
@greaterThan({fieldName: 'start'})
end: Time;
```

If I put the start time at 13:00 and the end time at 14:00 all works fine, but if I put the same hour, like start: 13:00 / end: 13:30 the validator always returns invalid.

Comment: Hi, not an answer to your question but I've never seen these decorators before with reactive forms. Could you point me to an example or documentation where @time(), @greaterThan() reside?

Comment: Hi, here you find the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators and here an example with @time() decorator https://stackblitz.com/edit/complete-rxweb-time-validation-add-angular-reactive-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fattandance-detail%2Fattandance-detail.model.ts